# The best way to compare two arrays when there are infinite CPUs?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, parallel-processing

It's a problem I faced on an interview. There are two sorted array A and B. Check if each element in array A appears in array B. Suppose there are infinite CPU cores. The interviewer suggested that the algorithms should run in O(1). I only came up with an O(log(n)) solution. Any ideas?

P.S. My O(log(n)) solution is that assign one element in A to one CPU core, each CPU use binary search to check if the element exists in array B. I recall that the interviewer might have suggested that the binary search can be optimized to O(1) given infinite CPUs. But I'm not sure about it. Just in case.

Comment: Can you have repeated elements in A and B?

Comment: To actually make your solution O(log n), you need to describe how to combine the answers from each of those n CPUs together into a single "YES/NO" answer in O(log n) time.  You could e.g. arrange the CPUs into a binary tree structure, so that two "child" CPUs pass their result to their shared parent, who passes it on up the tree towards the root, who calculates the final answer.

Comment: @displayName Yes, there can be.

Comment: @j_random_hacker So summarizing the answers should cause an additional O(logn) time?

Comment: @SieKensou: Then please look at my solution and let me know what you don't get...

Comment: @SieKensou: It could, depending on how you do it -- but the ways that you are allowed to do it depend on what model of parallelism you're assuming.  The way I suggested will take O(log n) time, and TTBOMK will work on any standard model; while Niklas B.'s O(1) way (for instance) assumes the ability for multiple processes to make simultaneous writes to a memory address, provided that they all write the same value.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You can compute prefix minima in O(log log n) time too in a CREW model, which can be used to solve the ANDs and ORs. I think a corresponding lower bound exists, so that gives a lower bound for any solution based on logic aggregations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an O(1) [PRAM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_random-access_machine) in the Common CRCW model, i.e. you can have concurrent writes only if the same value is written. Say the original array A has n elements and B has size m.

```
found = new bool[n]
parallel for i in 0..n-1:
  found[i] = false
  parallel for j in 0..m-1: 
    if A[i] == B[j]:
      found[i] = true

result = true
parallel for i in 0..n-1:
  if !found[i]:
    result = false

print result ? "Yes": "No"
```

Of course I'm not entirely sure how practical of a model this is. In reality you probably don't have concurrent writes. In a CREW model with exclusive writes, you can compute AND and OR aggregations in O(log log n) time, and I think a corresponding lower bound exists as well.

It might have been a good idea to ask your interviewer about the specifics of the parallel model he is interested in.

Comment: What's the need of the intermediate array `found` ? `if A[i] == A[j] result = true`  is enough.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not really. found[i] has to be true for all i. At least that's how I understand the problem

Answer (score 2):

Let each core take on one element from A, and a pair of adjacent elements from B. Use a different core for every possible combination. The cores will each compare their three elements. If the element from A is ever between the two from B (and not equal to either) then there is an element from A that doesn't appear in B.

This is missing some obvious optimizations. E.g., a1000 doesn't need to be compared to b1 & b2, but with infinite machines, who cares.

Comment: Also need a CPU for each element of A to check whether it precedes the first element of B, or comes after the last element.  This doesn't change things much though.

Comment: I still think you need some way to gather together all these answers together in O(1) time though...

Comment: When a core finds an element between the values it can signal the first core (maybe set a shared memory bit), so that's O(1). To prove the sequence doesn't match you only need the first example of it failing and you know if nobody sets the bit within one cycle that the sequence is good. @j_random_hacker

Comment: @IanMercer: Based on Niklas B.'s answer, that seems to work if we have a CRCW model, since any writes would be writing the same value.  And I suspect that if concurrent, equal-valued writes are not permitted, then no O(1) solution is possible...

Answer (score 1):

Let A have total *a* elements and B have total *b* elements (and I'm assuming that the elements may be repeated).

We will need **total *((a * b) + 1)* cores**: We want to check each element of A in B. So we need total *b* processors for each element of A, therefore *a * b*. Last *+1* is for a lead processor which runs the main program.

Each processor will simply compare if two elements are equal or not. If they are, it will return `true`, else `false`. Take A[0] for example. We just compare if *any* element of B is equal to A[0]. So we pass A[0] and B[0] to first processor, A[0] and B[1] to second processor and so on and do a OR over the result. Correspondingly, the code for `test()` method which will run on each core will be:

```
public static bool test (int aElement, int bElement)
{
    return aElement == bElement;
}
```

Next we do the same with A[1], then A[2].. till A[a-1] all of them in parallel.

We do an AND over this result, like:

```
(test(A[0], B[0]) || test(A[0], B[1])...) && (test(A[1], B[0]) || test(A[1], B[1])... )
```

So, the `Main()` will look like:

```
public void Main (string[] args)
{
    //Read A and B arrays and create the next line dynamically
    var allPresent = (test(A[0], B[0]) || test(A[0], B[1]) ||... test(A[0], B[b-1]))
                  && (test(A[1], B[0]) || test(A[1], B[1]) ||... test(A[1], B[b-1]))
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  && (test(A[a-1], B[0]) || test(A[a-1], B[1]) ||... test(A[a-1], B[b-1]))
    Console.WriteLine("All Elements {0}", (allPresent ? "Found" : "Not Found"));
}
```

We spawn all the `test(A[k], B[l])` in parallel, giving result in O(1) time.

Comment: I don't quite get how to do OR or AND over the result in O(1) time?

Comment: @SieKensou: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update :) I see how all the test(A[k], B[l]) can be done in O(1), but why does the process of doing OR and AND over a*b elements takes O(1) time instead of O(a*b)? Are there some special technology used?

Comment: @SieKensou: If I be honest with you, the questions seems wrong to me. Because, even to test the elements of A, you will have to at least read all of them and this will at least take O(a) time. However, I've assumed that by some magic, the correct section of array reaches the processors in constant time. There are no special tech used. It is a regular AND and OR assumed to fail and succeed faster... Like if one AND is `false`, the entire expression is `false` and if one OR is `true`, the  OR isn't evaluated further and taken to be `true`.

Comment: @SieKensou: AND and OR need a single bit (set to either 0 or 1), so their processing will be way faster than processing ints which are often 32 bits.

Comment: I have the same doubt too...It seems like a imaginary question :)

Answer (score 0):

To complement the very good answer by Niklas B., I am adding that for an O(1) solution, I doubt you can do with less than Ω(MN) cores in the worst case, even with sorted arrays.

If all elements appeared once in both arrays (and implicitly M=N), you could perform N comparisons in parallel, between "facing" elements, i.e. using Θ(N) cores.

But when repetitions are allowed, the equal elements can appear with a shift, which can grow as large as Ω(M+N) and isn't known in advance. To try all possible shifts for all elements, you perform Ω(MN) comparisons.